# SQL Server Report Builder Information in Parameter Pane

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to show additional information in the parameter pane based on the parameter the user selects? What I would like to do is allow the user to select a store from the parameter dropdown list and after the user selects the store they would be able to see the Store name, street address, city, state and zip to ensure they selected the correct store before they 'View Report'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, this is not possible, but I can propose a workaround, which is a bit silly, though.

1. Create a dataset which takes a Store ID as a parameter and returns the store name, address etc.
2. Add another several report parameters of type text that will represent the name, address etc correspondingly, and set their default values to the required fields in the dataset created in step 1.
3. Link the dataset's parameter to the report Parameter Store.

Once a user selects a store from the parameter dropdown, the rest parameters will be populated with the data.

Hope it hepls.